# How can I use Node.js Offline/locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, web-applications

Maybe i'm misunderstanding how Node.js works but, I would like to use it just as a server backend for a web app, without it running as a service/listening a port.

I'm willing to hear ideas to better solve the issue, this app will only be available on our intranet.

Example of what i'm thinking :

backend server.js :

```
function connectDb(usr, pwrd){
    //Some npm package code to connect to a db
    return console.log("Sucessfully connected")
}
```

frontend javascript.js :

```
require("server.js")

$(".connect.button").on("click", function(e){
    connectDb($(".connect.user").text(), $(".connect.pwrd").text())
})
```

Comment: You can't run a server unless it's listening on something (port, socket, other form of IPC).

Comment: @ssube I called it server.js just to diferentiate, I don't want it to be a server!

Comment: You want to use it as a server backend for a web app... how? If it can't hear anything from outside itself, how exactly will you communicate with it?

Comment: A web application needs to be hosted some where and that host is a _server_ that serves up the web pages.

Comment: @KimberlyW True, but in this case the OP is specifically wanting to use the Node app as an API-only server, meaning where the HTML/JS is served from is out-of-scope. The OP is a little confused about what that actually *means*, but AFAICT that's what's being asked about. Not sure.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes something like that, sorry for the confusion, I have full access to our server machines, I want it to just be a js interpreter using the npm modules, call it like a function instead of having it running all the time, if that makes sense

Comment: @Mojimi Nope, it doesn't. You don't call external processes as functions, you communicate with them. Web clients talk to the APIs they use over HTTP or WebSockets (in general). Those comms may be wrapped *up* in functions.

Comment: For local servers (no internet clients, only processes on the same machine), using system sockets or pipes is a popular way of setting up a server. Postgres is a good example, using a system socket by default.

Comment: @ssube - That isn't technically correct.  You can run a node.js process just fine that isn't listening on something.  For example, you could have a node.js process that was listening for events on some piece of hardware or polling some other server and then contacted some other server to do something.  For example, I have a fan controller on a raspberry pi that monitors temperature sensors and turns fans on and off via a relay based on the temperature sensors.  No listening on a port is needed.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's not a server, that's a daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different aspects with your question and code example on which you could work to get a better understanding of the ecosystem.

### Client / Server

When a client wants to get some resource from a server, it connects to a specific port on that server, on which the back-end application is "listening". That means, to be able to serve resources coming from a database, you must have a Node process listening to a port, fetching the requested resources from the database, and returning them. The perfect format for that kind of data exchange is JSON.
To get a better understanding of this process, you may want to try and write a simple Node app sending a piece of JSON over the network when it receives a request, and try to load it with an XHR in client code (for example with JQuery's AJAX method). Then, try and serve a dynamic piece of JSON coming from a database, with a query based on the request's content.

### Module loading

`require("server.js")` only works in Node, and can't be used in JavaScript that is running in a client's browser (Well, at least for now. Maybe some kind of module loading could be normalised for browsers, but that's another debate.).
To use a script in a client browser, you have to include it in the loaded page with a `<script>` tag.
In node, you can load a script file with `require`. However, said script must declare what functions or variables are exposed to the scripts that `require` it. To achieve it, you must export these variables or function setting `module.exports`.
See [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) to get some basic understanding, and [this part of Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to master all the details of module loading. This is quite important, as this will help you structure your app and avoid strange bugs.

Comment: That did clear things up, my line of thought was, well if both my backend and frontend are in the same machine, why do they need to communicate through ports, but I forgot about the database. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `node` itself isn't a web server: it's a JS interpreter, which (among other things) can be used to write a web server.  But `node` itself isn't a web server any more than Java is.

But if you want things to be able to connect to your `node` program, in order to do things like access a database, or serve a webpage, then, yeah, your program needs to be listening on some port on the machine it's running on.

Simply having your node program listening to a specific port on your machine doesn't mean that anyone else can access it; but that's really a networking question not a programming question.